# save image in a folder on your website without fileupload

Tags: android, file-upload

i have my website hosted on a server and i have a folder their named images.I am recieving a base64 string and convert it into an image and  saving it in my local directory and it works perfectly.

```
[WebMethod]
public void UploadPics(String imageString)
{
    //HttpRequest Request = new HttpRequest();
    //HttpPostedFile filePosted = new HttpPostedFile();
    string base64String = imageString;

    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    //string newFile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtensionApplication;
    string filePath = "C:/Users/MUWebServices/App_Code/images/pic1.jpg";
    image.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);       
}
```

But when i use

```
    string filePath = "http://mywebsite.com/images/pic1.jpg";
    image.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

received following exception 
"**System.ArgumentException**: URI formats are not supported" .

How can i save images on  website folder. I found some solutions but all were using **fileUpload** and i can't use that because i am receiving base64 image string from android and using this webservice to save images.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to upload the file. Since you are opening a TCP/IP connection to another computer you need to follow protocol to write that file to that remote directory. Let me explain this to you as Robert A. Heinlein
 once said,

> Anyone who considers protocol unimportant has never dealt with a cat. -Robert A. Heinlein

Jokes apart you still have to use file upload(you could do this via `AsyncTask`. A remote computer will most probably not use a uri for the same.

Comment: but i am making an app in android , so i can't use file upload :/
is their any other way it's possible to upload my image

Comment: You have to asynchronously upload the image. Refer http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: did it finally :)
used string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/images/pic1.jpg");
and ran it directly on my website and not localhost and it worked :D

Comment: Why would he accept your answer? He did not use it.

Comment: `filePath = Server.MapPath("~/images/pic1.jpg"); and ran it directly on my website and not localhost and it worked :D`. ??? Sorry but i do not understand a word you are telling here. Please explain.

Comment: @greenapps I assumed he did use my answer. I understand there is more than way to fry a fish. Forgive me if it seems otherwise.